# Google maps geocode request with a component - syntax

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to make a google-maps request with a component-filter and I can´t get the syntax right.

On the developers-site I can´t find it.

[Google-Maps Component-Filter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering)

I have this at the moment:

```
axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',{
                    params:{
                      address:location,
                      language: 'de',
                      components: (country | AT),
                      key:'APIKEY'
                    }
                  })
```

Because on the developers-site its written, that you should seperate pairs with a pipe...

I also tryed:

```
components: {country:AT}
```

and

```
components: ({country:AT})
```

None of it worked. Can someone help me, please.

Comment: How about: `{country: "AT"}`, that works [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1us9y350/1/) (admittedly the Javascript API, not the web service)

Comment: Okay, thanks, that works. But, the search isn´t restricted to "Austria". Do you know why?